# cellForItemAt never called in a class extends UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azFjJZxZP6M&index=12&list=PL0dzCUj1L5JEfHqwjBV0XFb9qx9cGXwkq) to create the UICollectionViewController, but the collection cells do not appear as expected. I added some print messages, and it turns out that numberOfItemsInSection is called, but cellForItemAt function is never called. Also, in viewDidLoad method, I printed out collectionView?.contentSize and it's (0.0, 0.0). Not sure what's the problem. Can anyone help explain?

More:
I found the problem might be that I didn't use pushViewController to navigate but use performSegue, so I didn't set UICollectionDelegateFlowLayout as the video did... Any way to fix it?

Comment: how did you write collectionView(cellForItemAt)? Do you have some code?

Comment: `    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "message cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        print("cell created")
        return cell
    }`

Comment: Can you put that in your question?

Comment: And whether a segue is used, or pushViewController, has no affect on cells in a collection view

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the function numberOfItemsInSection is return at least 1 or more? It will be helpful if you can paste some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set Datasource and Delegate of your UICollectionView.

```
yourcollectionview.delegate = self
yourcollectionview.dataSource = self
```