# CollectionView cellForItemAt never runs

Tags: swift, collectionview

Hi I have been searching for this a lot and couldn't get an appropriet answer. 
I am trying to populate a collectionView with data received online using an API. 
Data is returned but the collectionView cellForItemaAt never runs because when I use print statements nothing gets displayed.

I can't figure out what the problem is , I looked at these tow links but they werent't helpful :

[collectionView cellForItemAt not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51298015/collectionview-cellforitemat-not-being-called)

[cellForItemAt is not calling in collectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853189/cellforitemat-is-not-calling-in-collectionview)

[cellForItemAt never called in a class extends UICollectionViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372326/cellforitemat-never-called-in-a-class-extends-uicollectionviewcontroller)

here is the cellForItemAt method :

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {

        collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ItemCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCollectionViewCell
            cell.ItemNameLabel.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].name

            print(itemArray[indexPath.row].name)

            cell.priceLable.text = itemArray[indexPath.row].price + " " + itemArray[indexPath.row].currency

            guard let url : URL = URL(string:  itemArray[indexPath.row].image) else {return cell}

            cell.imageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
            cell.imageView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            cell.imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named:"placeholderImage"), options: .refreshCached, completed: nil)


            return cell

        }
```

here is the method I use to retrieve the data :

```
 func getAllItemsApiMethod()
    {
        itemArray.removeAll()
        if Reachability.sharedInstance.connectedToNetwork()
        {
            if searchShops == true {
                PostDict = ["page" : pageNumber ,"text" : searchKeyword,"searchShop" : "1"]
            }else{
                   PostDict = ["page":"1","text":searchKeyword]
            }

            print(PostDict)

            StartIndicator()
            WebServices.getItemsMethod(url: itemsUrl, parameters: PostDict) { (JsonResponse) in
                print(JsonResponse)
                StopIndicator()
                let json : JSON = JSON(JsonResponse)


               self.updateItemData(json: json)



                print(json)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FTIndicator.showToastMessage(Constant.NoInternet)
        }

    }


    func updateItemData (json : JSON) {
        let item = Item()

        for i in 0...json["data"].count - 1{
            item.name = json["data"][i]["title_ku"].stringValue
            item.price = json["data"][i]["price"].stringValue
            item.image = json["data"][i]["image"].stringValue
            item.currency = json["data"][i]["currency"].stringValue


        }

      //  useItemsCell = true
         self.collectionViewHome.reloadData()
    }
```

and here is the method i use to call the getAllItemsAPI :

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


        guard let searchKeyword = txtFldSearch.text else {return false}

        getAllItemsApiMethod()


        collectionViewHome.reloadData()

        self.view.endEditing(true)
        txtFldSearch.text = ""


        return true

    }
```

here is the numberOfItems method :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return itemArray.count

}
```

I have also set the datasource and collectionViewDelegate methods as self.

I have been searching for quite sometime to find an answer. Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Try replacing `self.collectionViewHome.reloadData()` with `DispatchQueue.main.async{self.collectionViewHome.reloadData()}`?

Comment: You never populate your `itemArray` with items. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `updateItemData` method you are parsing your `JSON`, but I don't see that you would be adding those items to any datasource object. You just iterate through the collection but do nothing with it, so when you reload the `collectionView` your data source is still empty. Make sure you add the items to your `itemArray`:

```
func updateItemData (json : JSON) {

    itemArray = []
    for i in 0...json["data"].count - 1{
        let item = Item()
        item.name = json["data"][i]["title_ku"].stringValue
        item.price = json["data"][i]["price"].stringValue
        item.image = json["data"][i]["image"].stringValue
        item.currency = json["data"][i]["currency"].stringValue
        itemArray.append(item)
    }

  //  useItemsCell = true
     self.collectionViewHome.reloadData()
}
```

Also if your API callback happens on non-main thread make sure you dispatch `collectionViewHome.reloadData()` to main one like someone mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Thank you so much Au Ris. You are a live saver. I can't believe I missed on such a simple thing and got so much head ache for it. Again Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way @Dyary if I answered your question please mark it as answered. That way you'll help others who may have a similar question :)